# In Python, How to use lambda reduction over a pd.DataFrame index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to slice a pd.DataFrame using lambda x over indexs, in order to apply a custom filtering method .

The following is in spirit what I am trying to replicate through lambda reduction:

```
DF = pd.DataFrame(columns = whatever) # dataset (scope is global)

def _selector(ix:int, iy:int) -> bool:
    ''' filtering method (pseudocode) , inputs: dataframe index values'''
    # some computation here involving DF.iloc[ix] and DF.iloc[iy]
    if 'conditions are met':    
        return True
    return False

def select(ix:int) -> pd.DataFrame:
    ''' this does the job but could it be done using lambda x ? '''
    keeps = []
    for iy in DF.index:
        if _selector(ix, iy) is True:
            keeps.append( iy )
    filtered = DF.iloc[keeps]
    return filtered

selected = select(22)
```

Tried quite a few tricks without any luck. For instance the following attempt got me a `KeyError: 'False: boolean label can not be used without a boolean index'`. Reading the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) I feel it should work...

```
def selectWithLambda(ix:int) -> pd.DataFrame:
    '''... I whish I could make this work ...'''
    reducer = lambda x: _selector(ix, x.index)    
    filtered = DF.loc[reducer]
    return filtered
```

I think I am still confused about pandas logic , any suggestions how to proceed ?

Thanks!

Comment: How about making a new column based on the index and then just dropping it later? `df['index'] = df.index`

Comment: @Minh-LongLuu Yes I thought about it , but it feels a bit  'moronic '.  I mean why have an index if you can't access it ?